# Limit display: table-row/cell element height when height is dynamic

Tags: html, css

I need to make a div scrollable when its content overflows. The catch is that for layout reasons, the div is part of a `display: table/table-row` system.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/helion3/pen/ucAKf)

The bottom sidebar container needs to allow scrolling when content exceeds the height. The problem I have is that - with this type of layout - CSS has no way of locking the lower div to the dynamically-determined height of its parent (`.holder`). It would either need to be a % height, or just 100% the height of its parent which is too big.

My goal is to resolve this with pure CSS so we can avoid running javascript when something changes the height of the sidebar elements.

```
.wrapper-page { position: absolute; top: 38px; bottom: 10px; left: 10px; right: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
.sidebar { width: 25%; height: 100%; }

.holder { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed }
.holder > div:first-child { height: 25%; max-height: 25%; }
.holder > div { display: table-row; table-layout: fixed  }
```

Because of this layout, only the `sidebar` will properly scroll if we use `overflow-y: scroll` - but that scrolls the entire sidebar. `.holder > div:last-child` is what should scroll.

```
<div class="wrapper-page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="holder">
            <div>
                box one<br>
            </div>
            <div>
                box two<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to use `box-sizing: border-box`? If so, set the height via percentage, then set the overflow to whichever configuration you like.

Comment: I can't use box-sizing because we have no choice but to support IE7, and the polyfill for that is too much a performance drain.

Comment: So, you're saying that `.holder > div:last-child { overflow-y: scroll; }` isn't working? Is this a limitation of the IE7 requirement or something else?

Comment: It's not working because there isn't any overflow. I have to use the `table-row` layout so that the last div will properly fill the remaining height in `.sidebar` (the top pane can be collapsed by the user, so I don't have any way of knowing the height for sure). This solves the height issue but tables expand to the height of their content, so there's no way to overflow the div. The only possible solution is to use a div inside with a max height - but with css alone, there's no way the div could know the correct height value.

Comment: Is it also impossible to actually use a table for this scenario?

Comment: It would resize to content just the same.

Comment: I added on to my answer, see if that helps or it might be another way to approach the problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working locally using:

```
div {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.wrapper-page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%
}
.holder {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.holder > div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.holder > div:first-child {
  height: 25%;
}
.holder > div:last-child {
  height: 75%;
}
```

I tried pasting back into CodePen but it does not work in their virtual environment. It does however work in a flat HTML file. Unfortunately I have no way of knowing if this would work for you other than to post it as a possible answer for you to review.

Explanation:
The caveat here was in fact the table structure itself. You will have to use the remaining size in height. That's the trade-off it seems; no-JS requires explicit CSS, where as with JS you can be more flexible with CSS.

Additionally you could use another class on the wrapper page so that you can hide the upper panel and expand the lower one like so:

```
.wrapper-page.hide-upper .holder > div:first-child { display: none !important; }
.wrapper-page.hide-upper .holder > div:last-child { height: 100% !important; }
```

It may not be 100% what you're looking for, but based on your description of what you're attempting to achieve, it sounds like it would do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, the reason this works is that height: 75%, which can't be used because in the actual app, the top pane can be collapsed by the user, which would increase the height of the lower pane. Leaving the height off is what allowed the table layout to resize automatically, without js. Thanks for the attempt though. For the time being, I'm just using javascript to calc the right height. Oh well

Comment: Yeah, interesting problem though. Perhaps if you allow them to close the upper panel, add a class to the container so that it just hides the top panel and expands the bottom one?